# Tkinter Key Binding in Different Regions of Window

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics, tic-tac-toe, 2d-games

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe program for 2 players, and so I need to be able to have mouse clicks in certain areas of the window do different things. How do I do that? This is what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
# Creates Window
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=600, height=600)
tk.title('Tic Tac Toe')
canvas.pack
# Creates Board
line1 = canvas.create_line(200, 0, 200, 600)
line2 = canvas.create_line(400, 0, 400, 600)
line3 = canvas.create_line(0, 200, 600, 200)
line4 = canvas.create_line(0, 400, 600, 400)

# Creates Functions for Xs being placed on board
def x1(event): 
    canvas.create_line(0, 0, 200, 200)
    canvas.create_line(200, 0, 0, 200)

def x2(event): 
    canvas.create_line(200, 0, 400, 200)
    canvas.create_line(400, 0, 200, 200)

# Creates the buttons to put the Xs on the board when clicked DOESN'T WORK
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", x1)
canvas.mainloop()
```

Sorry if I formatted the code wrong. The second to last line is the line I am having trouble with. I want button-1 (mouse click) to be able to do x1 and x2 (and eventually other functions) depending on the region of the window it is on. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the event co-ordinates to identify which square of the tic-tac-toe board the user clicked on:

```
from tkinter import *
# Creates Window
tk = Tk()

width = 600
third = width / 3

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=width, height=width)
tk.title('Tic Tac Toe')
canvas.pack
# Creates Board
canvas.create_line(third, 0, third, width)
canvas.create_line(third*2, 0, third*2, width)
canvas.create_line(0, third, width, third)
canvas.create_line(0, third*2, width, third*2)


def draw_cross(row,col):
    canvas.create_line(col * third, row * third, (col + 1) * third, (row + 1) * third)
    canvas.create_line((col + 1) * third, row * third, col * third, (row + 1) * third)

def mouse_click(event):
    col = int(event.x / third)
    row = int(event.y / third)
    draw_cross(row,col)

canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_click)
canvas.mainloop()
```

First of all I parametrized the board dimensions using variables *width* and *third* - just change *width*, and everything will resize correctly.

Second, clicking a mouse button on the canvas calls the *mouse_click* event handler, which obtains the co-ordinates of the point in the canvas on which the mouse was clicked (event.x and event.y), and computes the corresponding row (0, 1 or 2) and column (0, 1 or 2) of the square on the tic-tac-tow board. These are then passed as parameters to the function *draw_cross* which draws the two diagonals for that square.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I have another question about the same project in this link if you could help me with that too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938864/changing-variables-within-a-function-in-tkinter)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, you should upvote it and/or mark it as an accepted solution. That's how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

When function x1 is called in response to a mouse click, the event object has the mouse click x and y co-ordinates (event.x and event.y). Use those to detect which part of the canvas was clicked on and act accordingly.

Comment: Could you give an example on how I could make x1 happen in coordinates 0, 0, 200, 200? I am having a hard time understanding the terminology you used.